# How do you change background image in word business card

Tags: microsoft-word

I tried to do this https://www.wikihow.com/Make-Business-Cards-in-Microsoft-Word
"If the business card template has a placeholder logo, you can click it to replace it with your own. "

But I can't select the image to replace it.

Comment: You can change the logo picture in Business card. But about the Business card background, it is designed with Business card template and cannot be changed. You can change the Theme for Business card as a workaround: In Design tab, click Themes to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background images on the business cards are accessed from the Header layer of the document.

After creating a new business card document from one of the Business Card templates, double click in the header area of the document. This opens the header layer and from it you can click on the various shapes and images, and adjust them to your liking.

Included below is a screen clip of one of the Business Card templates where I have opened the header and selected a background image to adjust.

[image]